# Why can't Jekyll find gems that are presented in my Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundle, travis-ci

First of all, I'm aware that I'm running the risk that this question is already answered somewhere else, but because I don't know the origin of this issue I'm not sure what to search for to find the answer.

**The Problem**

I'm running bundle and Jekyll locally, which works perfectly fine. But when I install on Travis-CI, it presents me with the error `Could not find public_suffix-4.0.4 in any of the sources`. However, `public_suffix-4.0.4` is clearly in my Gemfile.lock.

**My Question**

What might be causing the problem and what hints should I look for to find an answer?

**Error message**

```
Could not find public_suffix-4.0.4 in any of the sources
```

**.travis.yml**

(relevant parts)

```yaml
script:
- gem install jekyll
- bundle install --full-index 
- bundle exec jekyll build -d _build
```

**Gemfile**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# gem "rails"

gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0"
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.12.2)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (1.8.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.0.0)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (>= 0.9.5, < 2)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 2.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (~> 3.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (~> 1.8)
    jekyll-sass-converter (2.1.0)
      sassc (> 2.0.1, < 3.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (2.1.0)
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.3)
    listen (3.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (4.0.4)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rouge (3.18.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    terminal-table (1.8.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    unicode-display_width (1.7.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll (~> 4.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another `bundle install` didn't work, delete `Gemfile.lock` then try specifying the version for `public_suffix` in `Gemfile` like so:

```
gem "public_suffix", "~> 4.0.4"
```

Then run:

```
bundle update jekyll
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: Thanks! That does result in `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown command public_suffix` though

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Can you run `gem install public_suffix --version 4.0.4`?

Comment: It's tough to reproduce the issue, maybe you can share the full logs?

Comment: That's actually it! But I'm not sure _why_... Thanks though :-)